# VB Net Charts on Non-Selected Tabs Do Not Locate Properly After Resizing Form

Tags: vb.net, charts, tabs, resize

I have 5 tabs on my form.  Each tab has 4 charts equally sized and spaced.  When I resize the form, the following will happen:

- Charts on the selected tab (which is visible) will resize and relocate properly (good)
- Charts on the non-selected tabs will resize correctly but not relocate properly (bug)
- If I select one of the 4 tabs that were not selected (call it tab A), then select any other tab, and back tab A, the charts will then relocate properly

I am not using Anchor or Dock but am doing this via code.  I initially tried Anchor (anchoring each chart to the 4 corners of the tab page but it didn't work when I tried resizing them).  Dock doesn't apply since I have 4 charts on each tab page.

So here is my code:

```
Dim origWidth As Integer = 1140
Dim origHeight As Integer = 900
Dim origChrtWidth As Integer = 495
Dim origChrtHeight As Integer = 325
Dim chrt As Chart

Private Sub myForm_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

    ' For each tab in tab control
    For Each c As Control In Me.tabCharts.Controls

        ' If tab has child
        If c.HasChildren Then

            Dim childControl As Control

            ' For each child control in tab
            For Each childControl In c.Controls

                chrt = TryCast(childControl, Chart)

                ' If child control is chart
                If (chrt IsNot Nothing) Then

                    chrt.Width = origChrtWidth + (Me.Width - origWidth) / 2
                    chrt.Height = origChrtHeight + (Me.Height - origHeight) / 2

                    Me.Refresh()

                    ' Charts are all named chart11, chart12, ..., chart21, chart22, etc.
                    ' Where 1st # is the tab, 2nd # is the chart
                    Select Case Integer.Parse(chrt.Name.Substring(chrt.Name.Length - 1, 1))

                        Case 1
                            chrt.Left = 7
                            chrt.Top = 10

                        Case 2
                            chrt.Left = 7 + origChrtWidth + (Me.Width - origWidth) / 2 + 7
                            chrt.Top = 10

                        Case 3
                            chrt.Left = 7
                            chrt.Top = 10 + origChrtHeight + (Me.Height - origHeight) / 2 + 7

                        Case 4
                            chrt.Left = 7 + origChrtWidth + (Me.Width - origWidth) / 2 + 7
                            chrt.Top = 10 + origChrtHeight + (Me.Height - origHeight) / 2 + 7

                    End Select

                    Me.Refresh()

                End If ' If child control is chart
            Next ' For each child control in tab
        End If ' If tab has child

    Next ' For each tab

End Sub
```

As mentioned, the above only worked properly for the selected tab and its charts.  So I added code to handle a tab selection event.  If the tab is selected, it should relocate the charts but this also did not work.  Only after selecting the non-selected tab, then another tab, and back to the non-selected tab would the charts update properly.

```
Private Sub tabCharts_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles tabCharts.Selected

    ' For each tab in tab control
    For Each c As Control In Me.tabCharts.Controls

        ' If tab has child
        If c.HasChildren And c.TabIndex = tabCharts.SelectedIndex Then

            Dim childControl As Control

            ' For each child control in tab
            For Each childControl In c.Controls

                chrt = TryCast(childControl, Chart)

                ' If child control is chart
                If (chrt IsNot Nothing) Then

                        ' Charts are all named chart11, chart12, ..., chart21, chart22, etc.
                        ' Where 1st # is the tab, 2nd # is the chart
                        Select Case Integer.Parse(chrt.Name.Substring(chrt.Name.Length - 1, 1))

                            Case 1
                                chrt.Left = 7
                                chrt.Top = 10

                            Case 2
                                chrt.Left = 7 + origChrtWidth + (Me.Width - origWidth) / 2 + 7
                                chrt.Top = 10

                            Case 3
                                chrt.Left = 7
                                chrt.Top = 10 + origChrtHeight + (Me.Height - origHeight) / 2 + 7

                            Case 4
                                chrt.Left = 7 + origChrtWidth + (Me.Width - origWidth) / 2 + 7
                                chrt.Top = 10 + origChrtHeight + (Me.Height - origHeight) / 2 + 7

                        End Select

                        Me.Refresh()

                End If ' If child control is chart
            Next ' For each child control in tab
        End If ' If tab has child

    Next ' For each tab

End Sub
```

I tried adding a loop to relocate twice.  Did not work.

I tried a work-around where upon selecting a tab, the form would size itself by +1 and -1 to resize and relocate the charts on the selected tab.  Works for the most part but there is a quick shift when the form does this.  Also, when the form is maximized, it cannot be changed in size so I have to set it to normal, change +1 -1, and then back to maximize, which is not quick enough.  The user will see an annoying flicker.  Here's the code for that.

I would prefer to fix the problem rather than use a work-around.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub tabCharts_Selected(sender As Object, e As TabControlEventArgs) Handles tabCharts.Selected

    Dim flagMax As Boolean

    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        flagMax = True
    End If

    If Me.Width = 1140 Then
        Me.Width = Me.Width + 1
        Me.Width = Me.Width - 1
    Else
        Me.Width = Me.Width - 1
        Me.Width = Me.Width + 1
    End If

    If flagMax = True Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to my problem.  Instead of coding the location and size, I added a Table Layout Panel into each Tab Page and placed the 4 charts from each tab into the Panel.

The Table Layout Panel was anchored in all directions while the charts themselves were docked to fill each cell of the Panel.  Works like a charm!